# How to prevent a webfont from being stolen using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, webfonts, restriction

I'm curious, is it possible to restrict a file (a webfont) from being downloaded by entering a path to the file in the address bar of a browser, and at the same time to allow viewing this webfont in the text, on a site?

I suggest that the restriction would completely restrict all access to the file, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. In order to display the font, the remote user's browser needs to download it. It's like wanting images to display but trying to prevent them from being downloaded. You can't have it both ways. You can obfuscate the process a bit, but you can't prevent it.